# jquery Accordion change Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I try is to have a simple Accordion that changes it text before you open it, it displays **show credits** and when it's open the text should change to **close credits** does someone knows how to do it? saw it on some sites and I wonder how to do it in jquery

```
     <!-- credits -->
    <div class="credits">
        <a class="show-credits" data-toggle="collapse" href="#credits" role="button"
           aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Show Credits
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="credits">
            <div class="card card-body">
                <div class="credits-body">Credits text .....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /. credits -->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you wish to do
https://codepen.io/wadleo/pen/mzMgpL

I used bootstrap and listen to its events on accordion open and close with jquery. Have fun.

https://codepen.io/wadleo/pen/mzMgpL

```js
$(function() {
 $("#paperback").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
  $(".pp-but").html('Paperback Close <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>');
 });
 $("#paperback").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
  $(".pp-but").html('Paperback Open <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>');
 });
});
```

```css
span, p {
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: Perpetua, sans-serif!important;
}

a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Perpetua, sans-serif!important; 
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


.btn-theme {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: solid 2px #FF7F50;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    background-color: #FF7F50;
    color: white;
}

.book-adds {
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.book-adds span {
    width: 50%;
}

.book-adds-cont {
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<div class="col-xs-6 book-adds">
  <span type="button" class="pp-but" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#paperback">Paperback Close <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span id="paperback" class="collapse">
    <a class="btn btn-theme" href="">Buy</a>
  </span>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me a lot appreciate your help man!

Comment: My pleasure helping out, thanks for accepting the solution, please don't forget to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [accordionbeforeactivate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate) event as:

```
$( "#accordion" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
  // 
} );
```

Below you can find a simple demo:

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  
  $( "#accordion" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    var oldHeaderText = ui.oldHeader.text()
    var newHeaderText = ui.newHeader.text()
    ui.oldHeader.text(oldHeaderText.replace(' - Open', ''));
    ui.newHeader.text(newHeaderText + ' - Open');
  } );
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
   
  <body>
     <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Section 1 - Open</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Paragraph 1
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3>Section 2</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Paragraph 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
 
</html>
```